# Copying weight painted faces from one .blend file to another

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, blend-files

So I have these two separate models, one is rigged and weight painted and another is just a copy with different bones and no weights. How can I copy the weights from the first model to the second one? 
If they both existed in the same project I could figure it out but they are in separate .blend files.

Original model
[image: pic1]

Copied model with automatic weights
[image: pic1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the correct weighted model into the wrong weighted blend file, then just rename its vertex groups accordingly to the names of the new armature's bones.